# Attempting to Understand Transistor Specs and Pick One

Tags: transistors

I'm trying to find a transistor that will power on with very low input. The entire circuit is running on 3.3 V, DC and needs to use little current (Max 50 mA). The resistance between the power supply and the "base" of the transistor will vary between 50kΩ to 120kΩ when on. Here's an image showing the circuit:

[image]

In the image you can see 2 of 4 sections that will be present. They are all the same.

What transistor should I use?

Comment: Why do you need transistors at all in this circuit?

Comment: Otherwise, the voltage drop across the resistor is too great to power the LED.

Comment: I don't think this circuit does what you think it does. What's the forward voltage of these LEDs? How much current do you want in each LED?

Comment: About 8-10 mA should be all that's needed, and the forward voltage would be between 1.8-2.4V.

Comment: Assuming the problem is that you can't make R1, R3 smaller, and they could be as much as \$120k\Omega\$, it will be difficult to make this work with BJTs. The maximum current you could get through that resistor is \$3.3V / 120k\Omega = 27\mu A\$, and you need a lot of current amplification to get to \$8ma\$, at least 290 times. Increasing the supply voltage will help. So will MOSFETs.

Comment: Why have a mechanical switch to turn on a transistor to turn on an LED... when you could just have a mechanical switch turn on the LED. Why the transistors?

Comment: The switch won't actually be in the final circuit, it's just in the diagram to symbolize that R1 or R3 can be between 50kΩ to 120kΩ, or completely open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a bipolar transistor. Use a MOSFET instead.

- Their on resistance is on the order of milliohms (so virtually zero voltage drop across the transistor)
- Have high impedance gates (no current flow into the gate)
- Come in numerous packages (easy to breadboard).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQkn3n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For your application, and with the circuit I included, you'll need to look for the following parameters.

- N channel enhancement MOSFET
- Logic Level gate with less than 3.3V drive voltage
- Your current will be low, be mindful of it, but I'm not seeing any on Digikey that will not work for you.
- The maximum \$V_{DS}\$ will no matter much either. The lowest I'm seeing is 5V. You'll be fine there.

For starters, [here's an example](http://www.vishay.com/docs/91310/sihld120.pdf).

Comment: From what I've found, the IRF9530 shown in your circuit is a P-channel, but you suggested using a N-channel. Putting the IRF9530 into my circuit simulator, it seems to work just fine though. Would there be any advantages to choosing a N-channel over the one in your diagram? EDIT: I've been trying out some N-channel ones in my simulator, and nothing's worked so far. I changed the input voltage to 5V (This would work too), and the IRF9530 works well.

Comment: @WiduX 2N7000 is a very common MOSFET that would work well at 5V.

Comment: N channels generally are cheaper and have lower on resistances.

Comment: @WiduX I guarantee if you're having trouble with N channel parts in Multisim, you have the drain and source flipped.

Comment: Hmm. I see that you switched the MOSFET in your diagram, and I've done so in the simulation. I've changed it back to 3.3V, and the LED doesn't seem to work. I've tried flipping the MOSFET, but this didn't work either. When I remove the MOSFET and make a direct connection, the LED turns on, so it's not an issue there.

Comment: The MOSFET in your circuit (IRF530) looks good. Do you think that this one would work on 5V? From what I see, it looks like it would work well.

Comment: It wouldn't be my first choice, but it would work.